# Calling toggleSidebar in Firefox's browser.js

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've seen numerous references to [browser.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js) while trying to create a Firefox sidebar. I don't have a good understanding of what this file is though. It has a method toggleSidebar in it. Can I call that method from a web page? Can I call it from a browser extension? Do I need to include browser.js in my extension somehow first? Can I call it from the add-on SDK or is it only available from the old style XUL extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have a good understanding of what this file is though.

It is the code driving the Firefox browser window, lots of code actually.

> Can I call that method from a web page?

No. You can use [window.sidebar.addPanel()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.sidebar) to add a sidebar however.

> Can I call it from a browser extension?

Yes.

> Do I need to include browser.js in my extension somehow first?

No, it is already included in the browser window.

> Can I call it from the add-on SDK or is it only available from the old style XUL extensions?

You can use it from the Add-on SDK as well but you will need to access the browser window directly - either via one of the low-level modules or [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html).